# Add pagination to UIViewController for endless scroll using the Combine framework

Tags: ios, swift, pagination, uikit, combine

Let's say I have some API calls that retrieve a list of items for the given page:

```swift
func getItemsA(_ page: Int) -> AnyPublisher<[A], Never>
func getItemsB(_ page: Int) -> AnyPublisher<[B], Never>
// (and more)
```

I want to create a generic `UIViewController` with an endless scroll (page 1 - 10 items, page 2 - 20 items and so on) that takes a
`(Int)->AnyPublisher<[T], Never>` closure and does as much work internally as possible (hidden from the outside world)

Currently what I have is something like this (again, I simplify the code to highlight the important parts)

```swift
// PagedCollectionViewController.swift
class PagedCollectionViewController<T>: UIViewController,
                                        UICollectionViewDelegate {

@Published var items: [T] = []
private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
var getItems: ((Int) -> AnyPublisher<[T], Never>)?

// (...)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        $items.sink { _ in
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }.store(in: &subscriptions)

        // get the items on the initial call
        getItems?(currentPage).sink { newItems in
            self.items.append(contentsOf: newItems)
        }.store(in: &subscriptions)
    }

// (...)

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell,
                        forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let itemsCount = collectionView
            .numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section)

       // everytime the user reaches the end of the list we need to load more items
        if indexPath.row == itemsCount - 1 {
           getItems?(currentPage).sink { newItems in
              self.items.append(contentsOf: newItems)
           }.store(in: &subscriptions)
        }
    }
}

// HomeViewController.swift
final class HomeViewController: PagedCollectionViewController<A> {

(...)
override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        getItems = interactor?.getItemsA
    }
}
```

So I'm mostly interested in the `getItems` part of the `PagedCollectionViewController`. I'm new to Combine and I find it kinda odd that I have the `sink` method called twice on `getItems`. Is there a better way of doing it?

The `PagedCollectionViewController` will be used with many other controllers and I expect it to work everywhere the same way thats why I want to keep it as generic as possible. Do You have any suggestions how to improve it? Maybe using Combine for this exact part (loading more items) is a bad idea in general? Would You solve the pagination problem differently?

Comment: "I want to create a generic UICollectionViewController"  Que!?  Where are you using `UICollectionViewController`?

Comment: @ElTomato hah, I was thinking purely on the behaviour of the controller. So sorry for the confusion, was not my intention, I want to create a VC that fetches pages when scrolling to the bottom using combine and making it as generic and user friendly as possible